# Why is BLAS dsyrk more precise than a naive C implementation?

Tags: c, precision, blas

I'm trying to find out why the BLAS dsyrk symmetric matrix product `A'*A`, is more precise than a C routine doing the same thing.

Here's how I've tested this: I've used the following Python code to compute the product very precisely using the `mpmath` package:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# file: make_precise.py

import mpmath

DPS = 100

def write_matrix(A, label):
    fname = './dataset_%s.txt' % label
    with open(fname, 'w') as fid:
        for i in range(A.rows):
            for j in range(A.cols):
                pre = '' if j == 0 else ' '
                fid.write(pre + mpmath.nstr(A[i, j], DPS))
            fid.write('\n')
    print("Created %s" % fname)


def main():
    mpmath.mp.dps = DPS

    A = mpmath.randmatrix(10000, 10)
    write_matrix(A, 'A')

    AA = A.T * A
    write_matrix(AA, 'AA')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `mpmath` package computes the product `A'*A` using about 100 decimals in precision. Now in C I'm comparing the precision of the product computed by BLAS using `dsyrk` with the precision of the product computed in standard C code. The "naive" C code is based on line 332 - 350 of [dsyrk.c](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/cblas/dsyrk.c). The code I use to compare the implementations is:

```c
// file: minimal.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N_OBS 10000
#define N_VAR 10

// generate datasets with:
// python make_precise.py

// compile with:
// gcc minimal.c -o minimal -lcblas -lm

void dsyrk_aa(const double *A, double *AA)
{
    cblas_dsyrk(CblasRowMajor, CblasUpper, CblasTrans, N_VAR, N_OBS, 1.0,
            A, N_VAR, 0., AA, N_VAR);
}


void naive_aa(double *A, double *AA)
{
    int i, j, k;
    double temp;

    for (j=0; j<N_VAR; j++) {
        for (k=j; k<N_VAR; k++) {
            temp = 0.0;
            for (i=0; i<N_OBS; i++) {
                temp += A[i*N_VAR+k] * A[i*N_VAR+j];
            }
            AA[j*N_VAR+k] = temp;
        }
    }
}


double *read_data(const char *name, int rows, int cols)
{
    int i, j;
    double value, *M = NULL;

    char filename[1024];
    sprintf(filename, "./dataset_%s.txt", name);
    FILE *fid = fopen(filename, "r");

    M = malloc(sizeof(double)*rows*cols);

    for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            fscanf(fid, "%lf", &value);
            M[i*cols+j] = value;
        }
    }

    fclose(fid);
    return M;
}


double dist_from_true(double *A, double *B, int rows, int cols)
{
    int i, j;
    double dist = 0.0;
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        for (j=i; j<cols; j++)
            dist += fabs(A[i*cols+j] - B[i*cols+j]);
    return dist;
}


int main()
{
    double d1, d2;
    double *A = NULL,
           *AA = NULL;

    double *AA1 = calloc(N_VAR*N_VAR, sizeof(double));
    double *AA2 = calloc(N_VAR*N_VAR, sizeof(double));

    A = read_data("A", N_OBS, N_VAR);
    AA = read_data("AA", N_VAR, N_VAR);

    dsyrk_aa(A, AA1);
    naive_aa(A, AA2);

    d1 = dist_from_true(AA, AA1, N_VAR, N_VAR);
    d2 = dist_from_true(AA, AA2, N_VAR, N_VAR);

    free(A);
    free(AA);

    free(AA1);
    free(AA2);

    printf("Dsyrk:  \t%.16f\n", d1);
    printf("Naive:  \t%.16f\n", d2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that I'm only computing the upper triangle in both routines. Of course, by reading the datasets into C we will lose some precision, since everything will be stored as a `double`. However, we compare with the true product as computed with `mpmath`, so we should be able to compare the precision of both products. The outcome I get is:

```
Dsyrk:      0.0000000000923137
Naive:      0.0000000003306013
```

So with BLAS the absolute error is about 3 times smaller than with the C implementation. This is reproducible for multiple datasets and on multiple workstations (both running Linux). I know the difference might seem negligible but I'm dealing with larger datasets where the errors accumulate over time.

My question is: where does this difference come from, and is there something I can do to make the C implementation as precise as the BLAS implementation?

Thanks in advance for your time!

### Update

I've re-compiled ATLAS to see which compiler flags are used when compiling the `dsyrk` routines. I've narrowed it down to this line:

```sh
/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-6.2.1 -o ATL_drefsyrkLN.o -c -DL2SIZE=33554432 -I/tmp/ATLAS/build/include -I/tmp/ATLAS/build/..//include -I/tmp/ATLAS/build/..//include/contrib -DAdd_ -DF77_INTEGER=int -DStringSunStyle -DATL_OS_Linux -DATL_ARCH_Corei4 -DATL_CPUMHZ=3200 -DATL_AVXMAC -DATL_AVX -DATL_SSE3 -DATL_SSE2 -DATL_SSE1 -DATL_USE64BITS -DATL_GAS_x8664 -m64 -DATL_DYLIBS -DPentiumCPS=3200.000 -DATL_FULL_LAPACK -DATL_NCPU=4 -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -fPIC -m64 -fPIC /tmp/ATLAS/build/..//src/blas/reference/level3/ATL_drefsyrkLN.c
```

from which I think the important flags are:

```
-m64 -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -fPIC
```

However, when compiling the minimal example above with:

```
gcc -o minimal -m64 -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -O2 -mavx2 -mfma -fPIC minimal.c -lcblas -lm
```

the precision results are not affected. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you compile the C version (in particular, what math compiler flags were used)?  Do you know what compiler flags were used for BLAS?

Comment: @JoshMilthorpe I'm going to have to look into that. I'm using the Atlas version of BLAS. The C code above is compiled as mentioned in the file. I've been playing around with the `-mfpmath` flag of GCC, and when the 387 unit is used the "naive" C implementation is _more_ _precise_ than the BLAS code. I haven't been able to find out exactly how to match the BLAS precision though.

Answer (score 2):

Posting the solution as an answer for future reference. The hints by @rubenvb turned out to be useful. I've tracked down the exact path taken in the ATLAS library by the `cblas_dsyrk` routine. This is as follows:

1. cblas_dsyrk
2. ATL_syrk
3. ATL_dsprk
4. ATL_dsprk_rK
5. ATL_dprk_kmm
6. ATL_gNBmm
7. ATL_dpKBmm
8. ATL_dgpKBmm
9. ATL_dJIK0x0x56TN56x56x0_a1_bX
10. ATL_dJIK0x0x56TN1x1x4_a1_bX (which does all the work)

Now, the "block size" used by ATLAS for my CPU is `NB = 56`. For ease of testing, I've therefore reduced the test dataset to be a multiple of this (N_OBS = 9968 in `minimal.c` above). If this would not be the case, some routines similar to the last two in the list will be called for the remaining rows.

With the final function tracked down, I started testing the value of a single element of the outcome matrix `AA`. What I noticed was that the call to ATL_dprk_kmm is actually performed three times, with different blocks (rows) of the initial `A` matrix. These blocks are of size 3472, 3472, and 3024 rows respectively. For each of these blocks, a separate outcome matrix `AA` is constructed, which is finally added to the `AA` matrix of the user. This immediately leads to the solution, where in the naive function we too calculate `AA` in blocks:

```c
void newnaive_aa(const double *A, double *AA)
{
    int i, j, k, blk_start, blk_end;
    double temp;
    double *tmpAA = calloc(N_VAR*N_VAR, sizeof(double));

    // block 1
    blk_start = 0; blk_end = 3472;
    for (j=0; j<N_VAR; j++) {
        for (k=j; k<N_VAR; k++) {
            temp = 0.0;
            for (i=blk_start; i<blk_end; i++) {
                temp += A[i*N_VAR+k] * A[i*N_VAR+j];
            }
            tmpAA[j*N_VAR+k] = temp;
        }
    }
    // copy matrix over
    for (j=0; j<N_VAR*N_VAR; j++)
        AA[j] += tmpAA[j];

    // block 2
    blk_start = 3472; blk_end = 6944;
    for (j=0; j<N_VAR; j++) {
        for (k=j; k<N_VAR; k++) {
            temp = 0.0;
            for (i=blk_start; i<blk_end; i++) {
                temp += A[i*N_VAR+k] * A[i*N_VAR+j];
            }
            tmpAA[j*N_VAR+k] = temp;
        }
    }
    // copy matrix over
    for (j=0; j<N_VAR*N_VAR; j++)
        AA[j] += tmpAA[j];

    // block 3
    blk_start = 6944; blk_end = 9968;
    for (j=0; j<N_VAR; j++) {
        for (k=j; k<N_VAR; k++) {
            temp = 0.0;
            for (i=blk_start; i<blk_end; i++) {
                temp += A[i*N_VAR+k] * A[i*N_VAR+j];
            }
            tmpAA[j*N_VAR+k] = temp;
        }
    }
    // copy matrix over
    for (j=0; j<N_VAR*N_VAR; j++)
        AA[j] += tmpAA[j];

    free(tmpAA);
}
```

With this new implementation, the exact same precision is obtained as with the `dsyrk` call.

Note also that with datasets containing a smaller number of rows (say N_OBS = 1000), the precision of the original `naive_aa` is already the same as that of the `dsyrk` result. The reason for this is now obvious because no intermediate results are needed for that dataset size.

Answer (score 1):

BLAS is an extremely optimized set of routines, it should come as no surprise that the authors, contributors, and users hold both speed and precision in high esteem.

You can make your own implementation exactly as precise by copying the (C)BLAS code. Do take the license into account, it's not your code.

Often the difference comes from a specific order of operations, compiler options, etc... There is no straightforward way to guide you to a better precision *in general*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While you are correct, the "naive" C code I've included _is_ an exact copy of the CBLAS code. So it should have the same precision, but as the test demonstrates, it doesn't.

Comment: Then it comes down to the exact compiler options used. Try to find out how your BLAS was built and use the exact same options. If even then there is still a difference, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've updated my post with information on the compile flags used. Unfortunately there's still a difference when using the exact same flags.

Comment: You forgot to include all the architecture and SSE defines in your slimmed down list of compiler flags... Although they may not affect this snippet. Are you sure the call to `blas_dsyrk` goes straight to your copied code, and there are no optimization-selection intermediate functions being called?

Comment: Just to be sure I've tested with these flags, but they don't affect anything. This makes sense, since they are macros for the ATLAS library, not for my minimal.c program.

Comment: @GJJ then my final and last idea is that your BLAS library is not calling the copied code directly, instead going through some CPU architecture detection system to select a different implementation than the one you copied (e.g. I know FFTW uses a system like this, but I don't know if ATLAS does). If that is not the case, I have no clue.